# Is there a difference between mysqli->prepare() and stmt->prepare()?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = ?';

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $ColumnValue);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Col1, $Col2);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

// or

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $ColumnValue);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Col1, $Col2);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

When dealing with prepared statements, what's the difference? Which should be used?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. I deleted my answer because I don't think it's relevant now. The two methods are different approaches to accomplish the same thing. I like the second better, because it uses one less step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli.c#L1030), they both do the same thing. Personally, I'd go with the one that involves less typing since both are equally readable.

Comment: Thank you for this resource, it is quite handy.